# Google Analytics: How to track how many times a specific user has viewed a type of page?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I have a set of n pages. I need to be able to break down how many different pages each user has viewed in the set. This is a per user calculation.

In other words, I'm trying to provide a report that groups users into buckets of usage. For example, how many users have viewed a page between 1 and 10 times,  how many users have viewed a page between 11 and 20 times, etc.

I've looked into custom metrics and dimensions, but haven't had much luck in figuring a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom segments are what you need if you want to put people into specific buckets based on some condition.

Go to Segments -> New Segment -> Advanced -> Conditions -> then choose Pageviews. Then on your right you can see logical operator for combining more conditions. Remember to choose "Include" (because you want to include, not exclude, people based on some condition).

If you think "per user", I suggest you to not consider data older than 1 month in your reports, or it would be useless. Lot of people delete cookies.

Comment: There are a few different types of pages on the site, and for the purpose of this report I only want to track the number of users that had between say 1 and 10 page views of this specific page. Is it possible to specify something like this via a segment?

Comment: Yes. You can select the target pages as conditions of the segment. If you want to select lot of pages, it's more practical to first add a custom dimension to these pages, then to add that custom dimension as a condition. If you need further help, ask and I'll add some screenshots.

Comment: Will a condition like "Pageviews per user > 10 AND Page contains 'something'" do the right thing? Will it give users with greater than 10 pageviews of pages that contain 'something', or will it give users that have greater than 10 total pageviews and also visited at least one page that contains 'something'?

Comment: Maybe you're right. I'll try later. The only alternative is an event that fires everytime a user sees that page, or a script with a counter that fires a custom dimension when user hits 10 times. But the event would be easier.